# Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-dom

I'm getting error in my test:

> Invariant failed: You should not use `<Link>` outside a `<Router>`

What can I do about this?

```
      483 |     state,
      484 |   }) => { 
    > 485 |     const component = mount(<Testrun  {...props} />);
          |                       ^
      486 |     return component;
      487 |   };
      488 |   it('should have an input for the username', function () {
```

Answer (score 2):

In real project your `<Testrun>` is nested into some parent and that is also wrapped with some parent and some of that parents have also `<BrowserRouter>` or `<HashRouter>`. 
They provide context(I mean React's [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) here) that is required for `<Link>`.

So you need some of Router version in your test. It will be as easily as

```
const component = mount(<MemoryRouter><Testrun  {...props} /></MemoryRouter>);
```

You can use any other router but [`MemoryRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md) is especially helpful in tests due to be easily configurable and controllable.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create Link tag inside children of Router

Answer (score -1):

There must be a  component which was applied outside the  component. Therefore, you are getting below error:
Invariant failed: You should not use  outside a .

Move the  component inside the  component.